# How to show Revision number when AssemblyVersion is specified in the csproj?

Tags: c#, csproj

Is there a way to see the 3rd and 4th number portion in the file version, when AssemblyVersion is defined in the csproj?

1. When I specify the csproj assembly version only in Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs, like the following:

```
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.0.*")]
```

...the file version is displayed as expected. All good here:

[image: correct file version]

2. However, when the file version is specified in csproj:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <Copyright>Copyright 2022 Hi Fry Inc.</Copyright>
      <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
      <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
      <!--<GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>-->
      <AssemblyVersion>7.0.*</AssemblyVersion>  <!-- HERE is the faulty setting. -->
    </PropertyGroup>
```

...the file version does not display the 3rd and 4th number portion:

[image: incorrect file version]

Is there a way to keep the version setting in csproj and show Build & Revision number in the 'Details' tab?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make the distinction between `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` here. `AssemblyVersion` is used during compilation for the project, but `AssemblyFileVersion` is simply a version number for file systems to display. From the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning):

> The assembly file version is used to display a file version in Windows and has no effect on run-time behavior. Setting this version is optional

So if you would like the file system to pick up on your build/revision numbers, you should specify the `FileVersion` property in your `csproj` as well.

```xml
<AssemblyVersion>7.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
<FileVersion>7.0.*</FileVersion>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But did you check if it shows the build/revision number? It does not on my side.